# explode does not work

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, explode

This Code is for inserting Units for certain specifications.
for example, if specification is length, then units are centimeter, meter and millimeter.

When I try to read all units in single text field with commas and in PHP tried to explode the units with comma.
But when I submit the form only the first unit is saved to DB.

This is my database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_unit` (
  `unit_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `unit_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `specification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`unit_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
$uid=$_POST['unitid'];
$unit=$_POST['unitname'];
$spec=$_POST['specification'];

$arr1 = explode(',',$unit);
$size=count($arr1);

for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
{
  mysql_query("insert into tbl_unit values('".$uid."','$arr1[$i]','".$specification."')");

}
 header('Location:addunit.php');
 ?>
```

What is confusing me is that when I try to insert `$arr1[0]`, `$arr1[1]` or `$arr1[2]` separately the values are being saved. I think the for loop is executing only once. what is the problem with for loop?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Also [the mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: `var_dump($arr1);` to see that explode works, i wouldn't explode blind. I'd consider a strpos check, like `if (strpos($unit, ',' ) !== FALSE) { echo "INPUT IS READY TO EXPLODE"; }`. You shouldn't query in a loop and why don't you check the return value of the Query (see http://php.net/mysqli_query)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 'primary key' constraint on unit_id, hence the first insert succeeds, but all the subsequent ones fail.

There are many other things I could point out here, but without having the full picture, I am just listing some major ones:

1) In mysql, it is preferable for a int primary key, so it is best to have such a column explicitly even if you don't use it. The 'unit_id' column which is a varchar can still have 'unique key' constraints if you want to enforce it.

2) If you have a unique constraint on 'unit_id', you will have to re-think your table spec. on how you want to capture multiple units. Maybe it should just be indexed without a unique constraint?

3) You haven't escaped or sanitized the input from $_POST before inserting them in a table - makes it vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

4) Depending upon the size of the array, you could do a 'batch insert' rather than looping for each insert - i.e. a singly mysql inset call with multiple row values supplied.

5) Minor thing on 'explode()' - it has a very subtle behavior on empty strings, so it is best to check for that (maybe as part of data sanitization checks mentioned in point 3) - e.g.:

```
php -r '$a = explode(",", ""); var_dump($a);'

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: thnx for the advices.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `unit_id` is a primary key in your table, but you are trying to insert multiple records with the same value for this column.  Each time through the loop, you insert using the same `unit_id` value, but a different `unit_name` value.  You can't do that as long as `unit_id` is a primary (or unique) key.

Comment: thnx alot.. :) i got it